avoiding capillary seepage of black urethane into mitered corner of floating picture frame


I have been using a manual Nobex miter saw on my picture frames for many years. I don't have the space for a chop saw where I'm presently working and prefer a manual saw for safety reasons. Sometimes my miters are a bit off, particularly when using imprecise scrap moldings I can sometimes pick up at the lumber yard vs. professional, precise hardwood picture frame moldings, which are more expensive. My miters have gotten better by clamping the moldings down before sawing. I paint the inner sides of the wooden painting panel or canvas black and the same on the inner side and bottom of the trough of the floating frame. Depending on the ground (white oil or alkyd), I'll use the black urethane or black oil paint. (I understand the particular black pigment dispersion in urethane (not polyurethane) I use doesn't need a primer on wood.)  I stain the frame and polyurethane it before I paint the inner sides black. Sometimes, even though I've applied polyurethane to the frame, a little sliver of black will seep into an imprecise miter. Is there any clear substance that might be useful to fill that miter crevice? Thanks for any info.
Thanks for the previous advice. I put together a miter trimming board and it seems to work. The final proof will be in the pudding; down the road the next time I make a frame.
Thanks. The miters came out much closer with the shooting board. As for evening out thicknesses of scrap lumber, that's another matter.


I'm sooo tempted to issue a frame challenge (haha) and say shoot your mitres, but superglue?

Thanks. Sawdust with glue works well sometimes in a crevice aesthetically, but may not be stable on an outer surface. I'll experiment with superglue or similar. Matching the wood color and texture is also sometimes difficult for touch-ups. Plastic wood seems to dry darker and may be too porous. Tamiya Putty does a nice job of filling in areas, but is bright white. As for the miters, perhaps I'll shop around for another not too space-intensive gadget.

There's really no way to reliably hand-saw absolutely perfect mitres, certainly not affordably. THE machine to do it and avoid having to shoot is a mitre trimmer, a type of guillotine, but they tend to be expensive (eye-wateringly) and may be a smidge too large for you as well. So sawing and then perfecting by shooting with a hand plane is by far the more usual way to get really accurate 45s that come together cleanly. But this route is predicated on A, having a hand plane and B, being able to sharpen to quite a high standard. If neither of those is the case it's a loong climb to the end goal.

@Graphus “There's really no way to reliably hand-saw absolutely perfect mitres” — this has certainly been my experience, but why is it the case, compared to, say, tenon shoulders, which books say must fit from the saw?

Thanks to both. I will make a simple, small miter shooting board. I hadn't known of this process until it was mentioned here. I have a very good hand plane and have been able to sharpen the blade very well. (Although I was never able to slice the hairs off my arm with the blade as sometimes shown in sharpening videos.)

@stanch, books do indeed say that. There are a few possible explanations. First, I don't know that it was common practice even when the older books were first written; now it's very common in woodworking instruction for shoulders to be cleaned up by chisel work after sawing (which makes a lot of sense since it means the sawing need not be perfect every time, a hard call for non-pros). But where it was the way things were done the shoulder was invariably marked out by knife which yields a much better edge than otherwise of course. And mitres are not marked out this way, so can't take advantage.

But… why not mark miters with a knife? Especially miters in mitered dovetails where everything else is already marked and typically fits from the saw. Whenever I see people making these, they always use a 45 degree block and chisel. (I say this as someone whose dovetails fit from the saw but miters misteriously don’t!)

First to tackle the Question as asked, superglue may be ideal here for smaller gaps.
Superglue or CA (cyanoacrylate) of course dries very fast, virtually instantaneously if an accelerator is used, can wick into gaps, Larger gaps should be mitigated in other ways I feel, however the wide end of a V-shaped gap can still be filled using superglue, if necessary by filling layer by layer.
Note: if you need to scrape or sand off superglue excess you shouldn't wait around too long. Superglue dries hard initially, but after a full curing period (perhaps 24 hours when it dries on its own) it becomes substantially harder. The hardness of fully cured superglue means that you may encounter problems with the softer wood around the fill dishing out during sanding, especially if using softwoods.
But as covered in the Comments previously, my frame challenge was not to work for a solution to this problem, to fix it after it happens (or try to), but instead to work to avoid it in the first place — a classic prevention is better than cure.
Frame challenge
Sawing by hand, by possibly any means (including the use of expensive jigs), it is impossible to consistently produce accurate 45° mitres in frame elements of all shapes and sizes. And mitre joints have to be dead-nuts accurate to come together properly, since even an error as small as half a degree can be too much. In addition, sawn mitres in general don't have edges quite as clean as one would like — bottom edge if sawn with a Western saw, top edge if sawn with an Eastern-style saw that cuts on the pull stroke – and the sawn ends can also be less smooth than is ideal (both for the mitre to come together, and for strength after glueing. Both can possibly further compound issues of two mitres coming together to produce a perfect 90 with no gaps.
It's for these reasons that it is, and has long been, common practice to use a hand plane and a shooting board to shoot board ends for a high-end result (note, for both square and angled cuts). With a properly sharpened iron fitted shooting is capable of producing flawless surfaces, will always produce an accurately square or 45° end if done right, and also allows one to sneak up on a perfect fit.
Shooting boards can be bought, but they're so easy to make and there are now a great many guides online on how. For future readers, look around at a few, pick one you like and go for it. Don't over-analyse, as long as it's accurate any shooting board is better than no shooting board! And, like a lot of jigs and appliances for the shop, making one is a good skill-builder and just plain good fun. Additionally, jigs are a useful way to use up some of the scraps we all hoard because we're sure they'll come in handy some day..... today could be that day.
